# What does it mean by "Home page / Archives" in JetPack Site Stats?

Tags: seo, plugin-jetpack

[image: JetPack Stat Site visit Stat]
In the JetPack SiteStats, on the "Top Posts & Pages" the first page or link got most views (8) is the **Home page / Archives**. What does it actually denote?

[JetPack support](http://en.support.wordpress.com/stats/#top-posts-pages) says:

> **Top Posts & Pages**
>   This section of stats will list the Posts and Pages which have received the most views. A view is only counted for a post or page when the permalink URL is visited. For example, if a visitor reads a post titled “Hello World” while viewing the home page of your blog, the view will not be counted towards the post, only towards total views.

As the last line says, the home page won't be counted here, only the Permalink URLs will be counted. Then, which Archive does it mean? A category archive, a tag archive, a day archive, a month archive, a year archive — there are a lot of possibilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that it counts the hits for the homepage and all archive pages, specifically the ones you mentioned.

Comment: *Understanding* may not what reality is - please pose any reason or explanation why you are understanding like that.